# Get File that was `copied to output directory` in a class library

Tags: c#, .net

In a class library, I have a file that is set to *copy to output directory* at `NewFolder1/HTMLPage1.htm`.

I tried this:

```
var foo = File.ReadAllText("NewFolder1/HTMLPage1.htm");
```

But the error is:

`ould not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\NewFolder1\HTMLPage1.htm'.`

How do I read this file?

Comment: What is using this library? From the error you see it appears to be the Development web server. If so then Eduardo's answer should work. Since you're using a relative path in your example, it becomes important to know what application and kind of application is using your class library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var foo = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("NewFolder1/HTMLPage1.htm"));
```

If you place the above code in an MVC controller action you can change Server to this.HttpContext.Server to work

Comment: I cant. I have no access to `Server`. Something else may call the method in the class library other than an mvc app.

Comment: Please edit the question to be clear, your code is in an MVC controller action or is in an external class library? If it's in an external class library you can reference the System.Web.dll assembly and use HttpContext.Current.Server(...)